# Is there a python builtin for merging dicts where I can pass the function to run when there's key conflicts?

Tags: python

Exactly what it says on the tin.

Is there a builtin python function that will do this?

```
la = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}
na = {'a':[7,8,9],'b':[1,2,3]}

la = la.update(na, merge=lambda a,b: a.extend(b))
```

Comment: You don't need what you think you need. If you state your question correctly, the answer will probably be [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: Oh! yeah that's what I need. If you care to make that an answer I'll check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a builtin, but the following should do what you want:

```
for k, v in na.items():
    la.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
```

Example:

```
>>> la = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}
>>> na = {'a':[7,8,9],'b':[1,2,3]}
>>> for k, v in na.items():
...     la.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
...
>>> la
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], 'b': [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]}
```